# I want to post ArrayList, but return null value

Tags: spring-boot

POSTMAN   :

```
{
    "childDTO":[{
            "age":"80",
        "gender":"kavi",
        "occupation":"main",
        "type":"mainlife"
    },  
    {       "age":"80",
        "gender":"kavi",
        "occupation":"main",
        "type":"mainlife"
    }
    ]
}
```

Controller.....

```
@PostMapping("/child")
public List<CustomerDTO> childDTO(@RequestBody CustomerDTO cus){

return calculationService.childDTO(cus.getAge(),cus.getGender(),cus.getOccupation(),cus.getType());
}
```

Service......

```
public List<CustomerDTO> childDTO(String age, String gender, String occupation, String type);
```

Service Impl......

@Override

```
public List<CustomerDTO> childDTO(String age, String gender, String occupation, String type) {

    List<CustomerDTO> typeChild = new ArrayList<>();
    if (type==children) {
        for (CustomerDTO customer1 : typeChild) {
            customer1.setAge(age);
            customer1.setGender(gender);
            customer1.setOccupation(occupation);
            customer1.setType(type);
            customer1.setBenifits(benifitDTO(beni.getRiders(), beni.getSumAssuarance()));
            System.out.println("list:-"+customer1);
            typeChild.add(customer1);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("list:-"+typeChild);
    return typeChild;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post code of `CustomerDTO` ? and What value children will have!

Comment: private String age;
 private String gender;
 private String occupation;
 private String type;
 private BenifitsDTO benifits;

Comment: So I think you post request will never be received as You're passing array data and in `@RequestBody` you're trying to receive data in single object !

Comment: controller :-CustomerDTO [age=null, gender=null, occupation=null, type=null, benifits=null]

Comment: post request data not assign in controller

Answer (score 1):

You did not post what variable `children` is, probably some class field, but you cannot compare Java Strings with `==`. Java Strings must be compared with `.equals`:

```
...
if (type.equals(children)) {
...
```

Use a debugger next time, to see what's happening in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your request and controller RequestBody structure do not match.
You need to use List.

```
@PostMapping("/child")
public List<CustomerDTO> childDTO(@RequestBody List<CustomerDTO> cusList){ // here list needs to be used
    if(cusList != null && !cusList.isEmpty()) {
        CustomerDTO cus = cusList.get(0); // it will get first element from the list, if you want to process all the elements then you need to iterate the list
        return calculationService.childDTO(cus.getAge(),cus.getGender(),cus.getOccupation(),cus.getType());
    }
}
```

Now other logic will be as it or you may change it as per your requirement.